# Gridview adapter from custom folder in sdcard

Tags: android, gridview

I m currenly using nhaarman gridview and i want to get the bitmap from custom folder.
The gridview is in fragment and it will pull the image from the "test" folder and show it.
The emulator able to run this code, but not in the real phone. 
 Anyone please help. Thanks.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_fragment_month, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_gridview_gv);


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Test");
    // Check for SD Card
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {

        if(file.exists()==false){
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Test");
            // Create a new folder if no folder named Test exist
            file.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = file.listFiles();
        // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
        FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
        // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
        FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            // Get the path of the image file
            FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            // Get the name image file
            FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
        }
    }

    SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getItems()));
    swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(gridView);
    swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setInitialDelayMillis(300);

    adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
    //gridView.setAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    // Declare variables
    private Context activity;
    private String[] filepath; 

 // file path , Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator +        "test"
    private String[] filename;

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context a, String[] fpath, String[] fname) {
        activity = a;
        filepath = fpath;
        filename = fname;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filepath.length;

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

        if (imageView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(activity);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }

        // Decode the filepath with BitmapFactory followed by the position
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

        // Set the decoded bitmap into ImageView
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the apk on device or using it for testing ? Because adding permissions might be an issue here if you are deploying the apk on real device.